# Is it possible to solve a PDE that depends on explicit evaluations of only 1 parameter, and if so, how?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, functional-equations

A while back, I asked how to solve a very ugly little duckling of a PDE, and if it could be done. No response. This is a better way repeating the question - if I have a PDE, where inside the equation itself, I have a term that is fixed in one parameter, but not the other, is the PDE solvable, and if so, how?
Say I have, 
$$
G_{t}(t,x) = a(x)G_{x}(t,0)+b(x)G_{x}(t,1)+c(x)G_{x}(t,x);\\
G(\infty,x)=0; \quad G(0,x)=f(x),
$$
where $f$ is some polynomial.  Is there any way to solve this, or is it a lost cause?

Now, I understand one may be tempted to say 
$$\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}(1,t)=g(t),$$
for some arbitrary function, $f$, but what then? It is certainly the case that $f(t)$ is in no way arbitrary, so how could one justify treating it as such?

EDIT: Upon having it pointed out that a PDE without boundary conditions can be nearly anything, I have decided to write a simplification of the problem that spawned this, to which I know the conditions constraining it. There aren't many.

Comment: I don't think that is a lost cause under some condition. In the present form of wording, the problem remains undefined. On other words, they are an infinity of solutions because no boundary or initial condition is specified. Solving it in this general case would be difficult, may be analytically  impossible. Can you specify a boundary or initial condition ?

Comment: Say, $u(x,0)=\alpha$, $u(x,\infty)=0$, $u_{x}(1,t)=\xi$. Does that help in some way? Mind you, this is an equation I pulled from thin air, and I am not confident enough as it stands to say "it should have this and this boundary condition". The idea of a boundary condition is slowly being shattered in my mind, too.

Comment: Without boundary or initial condition specified, the problem is so wide that probably a general solution cannot be expressed on explicit form. This is explained why in my answer. Thanks you for updating your question. But meanwhile I studied the original problem which was already rather arduous. Sorry I don't feel like studying the even more difficult version of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original wording of the question was :
$$u_t(x,t)=ax\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t)+bx^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1,t), \tag 1$$
Let $\quad\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1,t)=f(t).\quad$ Of course, at this point $f(t)$ is an unknown function which has to be determined later.

Rearranging :
$$-ax\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=bx^2f(t)\tag 2$$
The method of characteristic consists in solving the system of ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{-ax}=\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{bx^2f(t)}$$
A first family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad \frac{dx}{-ax}=\frac{dt}{1}.\quad$ Solving it leads to :
$$xe^{at}=c_1$$
A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{bx^2f(t)}$.

$du=bx^2f(t)dt=b\left(c_1e^{-at} \right)^2f(t)dt$
$$u-bc_1^2 \int_0^t e^{-2a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau =c_2$$
The general solution of Eq.$(2)$ comes from $\quad c_2=F(c_1)$

where $F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined according to some boundary or initial condition.
$$u-bc_1^2 \int_0^t e^{-2a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau  =F\left(xe^{at}\right)$$
$$u(x,t)=bx^2e^{2at} \int_0^t e^{-2a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau +F\left(xe^{at}\right)$$
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2bxe^{2at} \int_0^t e^{-2a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau +e^{at}F'\left(xe^{at}\right)$

$f(t)=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_{x=1}=2be^{2at} \int_0^t e^{-2a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau +e^{at}F'\left(e^{at}\right)$

So, we have to solve for $f(t)$ the integral equation :
$$f(t)=2be^{2at} \int_0^t e^{-2a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau +e^{at}F'\left(e^{at}\right)$$
Thus $f(t)$ depends on the arbitrary function $F$. This makes difficult the solving in the general case. That is why if a boundary or initial condition is specified, the problem becomes simpler.

For example, if the initial condition is :
$$u(x,0)=u_0(x),$$
we have $u(x,0)=bx^2e^{2at} \int_0^0 e^{-2a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau +F\left(xe^{0}\right)=F(x).$

The function $F$ is determined : $\quad F(x)=u_0(x)\quad$ which is a given function.

$$u(x,t)=bx^2e^{2at} \int_0^t e^{-2a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau +u_0\left(xe^{at}\right)$$
and the integral equation becomes :
$$f(t)=2be^{2at} \int_0^t e^{-2a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau +e^{at}u_0'\left(e^{at}\right)$$
$e^{-2at}f(t)= \int_0^t e^{-2a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau +e^{-at}u_0'\left(e^{at}\right)$

Differentiating leads to :

$-2ae^{-2at}f(t)+e^{-2at}f'(t)=e^{-2at}f(t)-ae^{-at}u_0'\left(e^{at}\right)+au_0''\left(e^{at}\right)$

Thus, $f(t)$ is solution of the differential equation :
$$f'(t)-(1+2a)f(t)  =-ae^{at}u_0'\left(e^{at}\right)+ae^{2at}u_0''\left(e^{at}\right)$$
This is a first order linear ODE. Since $u_0(t)$ is a known function, this ODE can be solved. The solution includes an arbitrary constant. Putting back the solution into the integral equation allows to determine the constant.

So, the function $f(t)$ is known now. With this, the solution of the PDE according to the initial condition is :
 $$u(x,t)=bx^2e^{2at} \int_0^t e^{-2a\tau}f(\tau)d\tau +u_0\left(xe^{at}\right)$$

Meanwhile, the wording of the question has change which makes it much more complicated because it involves some non-explicit functions $a(x)$ , $b(x)$ and $c(x)$. The integrals of those functions will appear into the calculus thanks to the method of characteristics. Probably an explicit solution will no longer be obtained for all kind of functions $a(x)$ , $b(x)$ and $c(x)$. Nevertheless, the simpler case above shows the method to tackle the problem.